# Array combination with custom style

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [supplierID] => 1
            [parkTypeID] => 1
            [cost] => 17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [supplierID] => 2
            [parkTypeID] => 1
            [cost] => 65
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [supplierID] => 2
            [parkTypeID] => 2
            [cost] => 30
        )

)
```

I want to combine elements which has same value for supplierID like this. Each key name's value has set in new array's keys.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 17
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 65
            [2] => 30
        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve your issue? The solution is as simple as single `foreach`

Comment: I tried with array_map(). But no luck. Is that such simple?

Comment: what result do you want??

Comment: I have mentioned that above

Comment: @Namal: iterate over array with `foreach` and fill another array with values.

Comment: if you can't find php library function create custom function like, create new results array, then use 2 `foreach` in above array, and using `in_array` to check already in array or not if not. If not then insert data in results array else leave it.

Comment: I can tell you exactly but we prefer, do it yourself, we are here to help you, not to write code for you. Using above logic it can be done.

Comment: This also has been asked before and was answered with many well explanations. Really no need to add this question again on this website. It's okay to struggle a bit for the correct terms to search for before asking a question. It's often even worth the time spend because you normally learn some interesting things while looking for the correct terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$r = array();
foreach ($array1 as $x) {
  if (array_key_exists($x['supplierID'], $r)
    $r[$x['supplierID']][$x['parkTypeID']] = $x['cost'];
  else      
    $r[$x['supplierID']] = array($x['parkTypeID'] => $x['cost']);
}
```

This will iterate over the initial array `$array1` and create a new array `$r` with the desired information.

For each element in the original array we check whether `supplierID` exists in `$r`.

If so, we just append the new correlation between the `parkTypeID` and the `cost` to the existing values.

If not, we add the `supplierID` to `$r` and assign it an array with only this pair of `parkTypeID` and `cost`.

---

A simplified version of the above code that relies on php to initialize an unset array index to an empty array when necessary is

```
$r = array();
foreach ($array1 as $x)
    $r[$x['supplierID']][$x['parkTypeID']] = $x['cost'];
```

Comment: Your solution would lose some data

Comment: You can vastly improve your answer by explaining how it works.

Comment: Worked :) . Actually 'if' doesn't need as @zerkms said.

Comment: Just remove the if statement. It doesn't need actually. This worked me exactly you trying to do. :) $r[$x['supplierName']] [$x['typeName']] =  $x['cost'];

Comment: @Namal It works by implicitly intitializing `$r[$x['supplierName']][$x['supplierID']]` to an empty array if it is not set. However, this is counter-intuitive and I strongly believe that the programmer should initialize the variables and not depend on the language to do it for him. I will add it as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_res = array_reduce($arr, function($t, $v) {
    if (!isset($t[$v['supplierID']]))
        $t[$v['supplierID']] = array();

    $t[$v['supplierID']][] = $v['cost'];
    return $t;
} , array());
```

Comment: Actually your `if` check isn't necessary. `[]` would create an array if it doesn't exist yet without notices. PS: `array_reduce` solution actually might be harmful for a newbie